# play 2 json suppress empty elements

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm using Play 2 case class inception to translate to/from POSO (plain old scala object) and json strings.

on the toJson write transform, I want the empty POSO vals (Strings and Lists) to not even show up in the json string... howto do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an implicit function `omitEmpty` quite easily.

```
implicit class RichJsObject(original: JsObject) {
  def omitEmpty: JsObject = original.value.foldLeft(original) { 
    case (obj, (key, JsString(st))) if st.isEmpty => obj - key
    case (obj, (key, JsArray(arr))) if arr.isEmpty => obj - key
    case (obj, (_, _)) => obj
  }
}
```

Then you can call `omitEmpty` on a `JsObject`.

```
scala> Json.obj("x" -> "", "y" -> JsArray()).omitEmpty
res5: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {}
```

Comment: Hey that works good when I implicitly create a JsObject ... but not sure howto use it via the inception via Json.toJson(POSO).

Comment: Define it on JsValue and use pattern-matching to avoid transforming non-JsObject JsValue instances.